# How can a Pakistani with an expired passport obtain travel document to travel to Pakistan?

Tags: passports, pakistani-citizens, deportation

My cousin overstayed in the US. His passport is expired. US Immigration wants to deport him. How would he get a travel document ? Would you send me the link of the website to download the form ?

Comment: With deportation in process, it seems like an emergency that calls for contacting the nearest Pakistan embassy or consulate, rather than downloading forms.

Comment: It's possible that Pakistan would allow you to enter with an expired passport, check with the embassy

Comment: You must visit the consulate in person to obtain an emergency travel document. Bring your expired passport and your CNIC/NICOP if you have one.

Comment: Well, my nephew is in immigration custody.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, this is a situation for the Pakistan consulate serving your area (see the "Consulates" tab on [this page](http://www.embassyofpakistanusa.org/) for a list). Your cousin will surely not be the only person they have seen in such a situation and they should be able to advise on the best way to get travel documents quickly.